# Android textures(drawables) references in XML file

Tags: android, resources, textures

I am creating an android game and I want to store a locations in external files so I can edit them out of the code. So why not XML files, sounds fine. There will be items, positions, etc. and ofc some reference which texture to use for which objects. I couldn't really find a proper way to do this. For now I only know about two solutions, but both have flaws:

1. String values in XML file and method getIdentifiers (I've heard this is very slow)
   example:
   `getResources().getIdentifier( "namexxx" , "drawable" , this.class.getPackageName() );`
2. Use assets folder and load textures manualy without R class (this will surely work, but I will lose the beauty of automatical drawable selection according to dpi/resolution of device)

Anybody knows better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In some of the bigger and more extensive games I've worked on, I've seen this type of approach**:

- On app installation, calculate what type of assets you are going to need for this device.
- This can be a calculation of screen density, size, etc., or could just be a lookup from an online table for a very specific popular device, like the Nexus 7.
- Download the correct asset package for that device for your game.

**This has multiple advantages.**

1. small app size and quick download
2. only store assets you need on your device (in a large game, the "necessities" can be 100's of MBytes)
3. no runtime calculations for what assets you need.

**so... you would need:**
- a site you can safely download from.
- a configuration file, which would help you decode which data you need for your device, and which you can update indefinitely
- multiple asset packages.

**That is the "high level" of what I would recommend.**

Comment: It's kinda overkill, but thanks :) Doesn't Google have a better way to solve this? I can't help it, but it seems like something very common.